# Does anyone know which Age of Empires map this is?

Tags: age-of-empires

I remember playing some AoE I map and I cannot remember which one it is. I think it could be from RoR expansion but I am not sure.

Scenario is like this: You start in bottom left as blue team and you have 2 priests. On top left side of map is some weak enemy so you can use priests to bring villagers to your side. And it is easy to defeat the first enemy. Second enemy is located on the right side of map, and the only way to reach him is to cut forest through bridge-like land. When you cut all the way through, you have to face the red enemy to win.

Layout is something like this:
[image]

I think I played this map from some demo version of maybe an expansion pack or something. Does anyone know what is the name of map/scenario and where it is? I do have AoE I, RoR and gold edition but still cannot find it.

Comment: I think it was the first map of the babylonian campaign. Don't remember if that was RoR only.

Comment: thanks, I'm listing through aoe & aoe ror walkthroughs and also downloading some savegames trying to find it but no luck. maybe it was only in some trial version. Do you (anyone) remember this map or am I loosing it xD

Comment: @nekome I recognize that map as I played the AOE/ROR demo a lot back then. It was a map available in the demo version. I don't remember if it's AOE or ROR's demo version. Probably AOE.

Comment: @nekome So you're sure the map looks exactly like this? There are two maps in the babylonian campaign which involves starting with a priest: Starting with one priest only and starting with one priest and a few soldiers.

Comment: Your link broke.  This is why Anna moved your picture.

Comment: you don't need to cut the forest to get to the second enemy. You can use boats and land in the north of the map

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the map Opening Moves, from the Reign of the Hittites campaign from the Age of Empires trial. The babylonian map from the full version does not have forest between the lands.

Comment: youtube.com/watch?v=F8rUZ4_71DU looks like we have a winner :). This is most precise answer. Thank you all.

Comment: yes, and I would add that you don't need to cut the forest to get to the second enemy. You can use boats and land in the north of the map.

Answer (score 7):

I remember a very similar scenario, from the Age of Empires Demo (found, amongst others, on the Windows 98 SE CD). However, a few details differ:

- You started in the south-east corner, with two priests.
- South-west was a small village with only villagers, who you could (and should) convert.
- There was a river between these two tribes and another tribe to the north, which you needed to cross in order to attack them. I think the rest of the map was fended off with cliffs.

Comment: @AshleyDavies Nostalgia indeed. I played this map dozens of times along with the Total Annihilation demo campaign. I remember installing full version campaign/scenario maps in the demo of AOE as there are software that can 'convert' full version campaign/scenario maps to demo maps. (I didn't have the full versions back then.)

Answer (score 3):

The map described above is infact only for the Age Of Empires Trial. And that version alone. It's the map where there is no way of aquiring gold unless you rush cargoships and invade red lands. There is a similar version to this awesome map in the full game called "Holy Man" and is a part of the Voices of Babylon campaign. However it's not nearly as brilliant nor exciting as the trial version where you start out with TWO priests.

Answer (score 2):

It's AOE demo map, I remeber playing it when I was little. I downloaded AOE few days ago again, and I have big urge to play this map :D

And it was excatly same map like you described. Plus gold was only on enemys side :-(

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This answer repeats an existing answer. Use your votes and comments to respond to those answers before making your own.

Answer (score 2):

The scenario you are describing is called "Holy Man" and is part of the Voices of Babylon campaign.  It's part of the origianl Age of Empires game.  The only difference from what is on my machine, and what you described, is you start out with a single (not two) priests, and there is a ford across the water, but you don't need to cut down forests to cross it.  It's a very fun scenario because you start out with ... just a priest.  Clever idea.